# How to I get data from array "data" key in codegnitor?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried but how to iterate this data from this object please help me. I serch but not succeed to iterate this.I tried but how to iterate this data from this object please help me.

```
$data [ 'center_list' ] => {
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Successful...",
    "data": [
        {
            "staff_id": "114",
            "staff_name": "DEEP SINGH",
            "level_type_id": "6",
            "level_type_name": "Center",
            "level_id": "2393",
            "level_name": "BORADHI SANGEETA JLG 3903",
            "from_date": "2019-07-11",
            "to_date": null
        },
        {
            "staff_id": "114",
            "staff_name": "DEEP SINGH",
            "level_type_id": "6",
            "level_type_name": "Center",
            "level_id": "2351",
            "level_name": "BADODIYA SANJU JLG 3902",
            "from_date": "2019-07-12",
            "to_date": null
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: how about `$data ['center_list']->data`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you have tried that isn't working.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a proper export of the variable using: `var_export($data);`. It's a bit unclear from the current posted data, but it looks like `center_list` contains a stringified json object. You should also include what you so far have attempted.

Comment: @AlwaysSunny not working.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thankyou it is stringfy json so thats why probleam to irate the json

Comment: Is that an exact copy of the complete json-string? The comma after the last object in that json string makes it invalid. Json doesn't allow for trailing commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
json_decode($data['data']);
```

This will return the result that you can iterate through.